# javascript :- get all inputs from webpage and print

Tags: javascript, html, web

I'm trying to get all inputs from the webpage and to print when the user click on the input field. I want when the user focuses on the input field to type print

Comment: why would you need a for loop when you are not using anything out of it?

Comment: what do you mean? i am using it. I'm getting all of the inputs from the loop and registering for the onfocus event for each input field

Comment: no you are not. `inputs` is the same in each iteration of the loop you are not taking each one separately.

Comment: Use inputs[i].onfocus instead of inputs.onfocus

Answer (score 1):

You have to apply onfocus on individual inputs. You are not using the index `i` at all.

Do this:

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; ++i) {
    inputs[i].onfocus = function() {
        console.log("focus");
    };
}
```

Easier if you can use jQuery:

```
$('input').focus(function(){console.log('Focus')});
```

Comment: Thanks! that works! what was my issue can you pls explian?

Comment: Each iteration of your for loop works on that particular input. That input in that particulat iteration corresponds to your index i. So you need to apply onfocus to each index, or iteration. You were trying to apply onfocus on your array. Not individual element.

Comment: Can you please select my answer if that works? Would appreciate :)

Answer (score 1):

Your code is almost correct. Just add `[i]` as done in the code below. That way your `onfocus` targets each input individually.

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; ++i) {
    inputs[i].onfocus = function() {
        console.log("focus");
    };
}
```